# http_post() variables to php script from SMS message but only append data to text file if certain variable (telephone number) equals a known

Tags: php, file, variables, text, fwrite

All,
I have an SMS gateway application running on my server that passes incoming SMS messages to a php script. That script writes the data to a text file. Certain aspects of the message can be extracted as variables - for example: Message content: $msgdata Sender: $originator Time: $receivedtime etc...
Using the script below I can easily write the message to a text file but it will write the data of every SMS that comes in. I only want to write to a text file if the $originator variable is a certain telephone number (e.g 07123456321)

```
$date = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");
$msgdata = $_REQUEST["msgdata"]; 
$myFile3 = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile3, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData3 = "$date - $msgdata\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData3);
fclose($fh);
```

Your assistance is bery much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can not do print_r for incoming messages you can frite $msgdata = $_REQUEST["msgdata"];  to your txt file. 
Then all you have to do is to open txt file and take a look at $originator key and then said:

```
 if($msgdata->originator_key == '07123456321'){
      //your function for writing to file here
   }
```

If I understood correctly the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to only write the message (run the write script) if the $originator variable = 07123456321. Does the script above do this? Cheers

Comment: first you need to catch a key name from your raw data. if $_REQUEST["msgdata"] is all elements of your message I told you, you have to fwrite raw message into file a get key name for originator. After you get that key name you will then say if(rawdata->keyname=='number'){ do this}

Comment: or mail that raw message to your email and paste data here so we can see how that raw message look like. this is how you to that (send email). foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
   $msg_send .= "".$key ." = ".$value."\r\n";
  }
 mail("youemailhere","subject here",$msg_send);